# android detect when view is over another view

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout:

[image]

What I want when I move any view of those is to detect if this view is over another view and, if so, call the `swap` method.

I want to do it when over on half of second view like in this example:

[image]

all code is complete, I just want to detect when view is over half view from right or left. My xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/mmmm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="false"
    android:layout_gravity="center">



             <!-- first view -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                <customfonts.RoundedImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/pro2"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

                <customfonts.MyTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/circulo"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                   />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- end first view -->

            <!-- second view -->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                <customfonts.RoundedImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/pro2"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

                <customfonts.MyTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/circulo"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                   />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- end secondview -->

            <!--  third view -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

                <customfonts.RoundedImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:src="@drawable/pro2"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="false" />

                <customfonts.MyTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/circulo"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                   />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <!-- end third view -->

        </RelativeLayout>
```

what i try

```
          float x1 = v.getX();
          float w1 = v.getWidth();



          float x2 = m.getView().getX();
          float w2 = m.getView().getWidth();

         if((x1+w1 >= x2 &&  x2 > x1)  || (x1 >= (x2 + w2/2) && (x2 + w2) > x1)){


      Log.d("overlay now","index is "+m.getIndex());


       }
```

this code i try it but its i don't know what the problem of it , it's like give wrong x and position

Comment: What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a 'Code this for me'-site.

Comment: @Tom i want idea not code _detect when view is over another view_
how i know if view is over half of another `View`

Comment: @Tom see update i write what i trying